# Different app-name for different countries possible?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I've released a Norwegian app for Windows Phone. I'm working on Danish and Swedish support now. But I'm wondering if I can use another app-name in the marketplace. Still the same app, but use another name for the app in e.g Sweden. So in Norway the app is called "App Name 1", and in Sweden "App Name 2".

Is this possible? Or do I need to publish 2 seperate apps to achieve this?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I think users would appreciate different applications, no matter whether its name is different or not. Simply because it could include only one localization file and will be small compared to an app with all possible localizations, which can grow in size a lot once you support all languages in the world. Well, unless your app is so big so it doesn't matter anymore.

Comment: Yes Vlad, I agree. My app is around 7mb for Norway, and it will grow with about 10mb more with the swedish support (images and files). So maybe it's best to seperate them..But it's more work updating 2-3 different apps later...That's the dillemma..

Comment: This is definitely possible, check out [this article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff967550%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) for a step-by-step tutorial

Comment: That's actually about the app-tile, and not the marketplace, but definitively a good addition, as he was probably going to ask about that too!

Comment: That sounded a bit negative Claus, like I'm asking for everything. I'm not a professional programmer, but trying to learn..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can specify a different name for each supported culture in the marketplace. Why did you ask? If you submitted it, you would have known.

Comment: Thanks (again) Claus. Yes, i did submit, but i didn't notice it. Because i didn't have any localization at that time.