# App Hub different Name for different Language

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm about to release my first WP7 app on AppHub.
My app supports german and english and it should have 2 different names in the marktplace.
Does anybody knows how to do this?

I've read this: [Different app-name for different countries possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866022/different-app-name-for-different-countries-possible)

I can make different descriptions, key words, etc. for german and english.
But i can't change the app name. 
In the msdn submission walkthrough ( http://create.msdn.com/en-US/home/about/app_submission_walkthrough) stands, that the app name is get from the xap-file. I found out that the app name is written in the WMAppManifest.xml

But how do i get there a second app name in?

Comment: I found a tut:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff967550%28v=VS.92%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have to do is localize the titles. This can be a fairly uncomplicated project in which you create a C++ project to make the dll files that will allow the localization of the tiles as explained here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff967550%28v=VS.92%29.aspx, or you can use this tool, http://patrickgetzmann.wordpress.com/wp7-localize/ created by Patrick Getzmann.

Once you create the dll files, there are a few small changes to the WMAppManifest.xml file that cause it to use those dll files.  You can find details at the tail end of this blog: http://hopnet.mobi/website/Blog/tabid/227/EntryId/1/Localized-Windows-Phone-App-Start-to-Finish.aspx

Hope this helps.